# Why can I not publish Spring Boot Web Service to MS Azure?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure

My students and I are having problems posting a Java SpringBoot web service to my pay as you go Azure subscription. We are following microsoft's directions from their [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-java?tabs=javase&pivots=platform-windows-development-environment-maven) site. We keep receiving *invalid target release: 17*

This is my code https://github.com/leecottrellPTC/Azurepublish.git
This is MS's code https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot

The version of Java in the Azure CLI is Java 11. I have tried rebuilding my project locally to Java versions 8, 11, and 17. Each time, it runs on my local servers. When I republish it to Azure, I make the proper version choices in the wizard. I have tried Linux and Windows OS, and several tiers of pay. Each results in the same error.

The MS Link offers four different ways to publish a web service. I have tried them all with the exception of Docker. I do not have that configured.

I have run the *mvn package azure-webapp:deploy -e*, receiving a vomit of errors.

I do not know what else to do.

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project azurehotel: Fatal error compiling: error: invalid target release: 17 -\> \[Help 1\]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project azurehotel: Fatal error compiling
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1220)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:198)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: error: invalid target release: 17
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:197)
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:182)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1209)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:198)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error: invalid target release: 17
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.error (Arguments.java:907)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.doProcessArgs (Arguments.java:383)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.processArgs (Arguments.java:347)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.init (Arguments.java:246)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:185)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:119)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:68)
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:135)
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:182)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1209)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:198)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
\[ERROR\]
\[ERROR\] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
\[ERROR\]
\[ERROR\] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
\[ERROR\] \[Help 1\] </kbd><kbd>http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading to Spring boot 2.7.10-snapshot worked. I was able to successfully transfer the web service from GitHub to Azure.

I was able to successfully upgrade the Azure cli to java 17, but it did not allow the service to post.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this in your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
```

To this:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

Spring-Boot 3 does require Java 17, so you'll need to downgrade to Spring-Boot 2. If that's not an option, you'll keep the pom.xml the same and change the Azure cli version to 17.

Comment: Downgrading to Spring-Boot 2 worked. I did try changing the Azure cli version to 10, but ran into the same issues.